# Extracting value from a xml file using awk

Tags: sed, awk

I have a text stream like this
`<device nid="05023CA70900" id="1" fblock="-1" type="switch" name="Appliance Home" brand="Google" active="false"  energy_lo="427" />

        <device nid="0501C1D82300" id="2" fblock="-1" type="switch" name="TELEVISION Home" brand="Google" active="pending"  energy_lo="3272" />`
from which i would like an output like
`05023CA70900@@1@@-1@@switch@@Appliance Home@@Google@@false@@427`
  `0501C1D82300@@2@@-1@@switch@@TELEVISION Home@@Google@@pending@@3272`
There are many lines in the input all of which are not writable.

How can we achieve this using awk or sed ?

Comment: Any reason you're parsing XML data using awk/sed? There are specialized tool for this.

Comment: Using a shell script in an embedded system have very limited resources for the same.i dont have access to any tools on such a barebone of a system. @anubhava

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following awk should work:

```
awk -F '"' '$1 == "<device nid=" { printf("%s@@%s@@%s@@%s@@%s@@%s@@%s@@%s\n", 
                    $2, $4, $6, $8, $10, $12, $14, $16)}' file
```

PS: It is not always best approach to parse XML using awk/sed.

Comment: Works like a charm my friend but just one little bit of help needed.Can we place a filter in awk itself which first detects if the line has a `<device nid` in the beginnig .Then it will suffice @anubhava

Answer (score 1):

Its very simple in perl . So why not use perl ?

```
perl -lne 'push @a,/\"([\S]*)\"/g;print join "@@",@a;undef @a' your_file
```

Sample tested:

```
> cat temp
<device nid="05023CA70900" id="1" fblock="-1" type="switch" name="Appliance Home" brand="Google" active="false"  energy_lo="427" />  
<device nid="0501C1D82300" id="2" fblock="-1" type="switch" name="TELEVISION Home" brand="Google" active="pending"  energy_lo="3272" />  
> perl -lne 'push @a,/\"([\S]*)\"/g;print join "@@",@a;undef @a' temp
05023CA70900@@1@@-1@@switch@@Google@@false@@427
0501C1D82300@@2@@-1@@switch@@Google@@pending@@3272
>
```

Comment: I dont have perl on my embedded device.But anyways thanks for the suggestion. @Vijay

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F\" -v OFS="@@" '/^<device nid=/ { print $2, $4, $6, $8, $10, $12, $14, $16 }' file
```

or more generally:

```
awk -F\" '/^<device nid=/ {for (i=2;i<=NF;i+=2) printf "%s%s",(i==2?"":"@@"),$i; print ""}' file
```

To address your question in your comment: If you could have a tab in front of `<device nid`:

```
awk -F\" '/^\t?<device nid=// ...'
```

If you meant something else, update your question and provide more representative input.

Comment: And if there is a tab in front of the "device nid".Can you please tell how to account for that. @Ed Morton